# How to open URL In WebView from inside TextView Link?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am getting `Web Data` and aI am setting it on `textView`. Ih web data, There is url. I i want to click on given `url` and it should be open inside `Application`, `WebView`. But its launching `new browser`. Please guide me. What I did is here ,

```
private void setTextViewHTML(TextView type_1_bodyTxt, String main_hrml) {
    CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(main_hrml);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
    for (URLSpan span : urls) {
        makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
    }

    if (main_hrml.contains("<p>")){
        if (!main_hrml.contains("<ul")) {
            GetDeviceResolution getDeviceResolution = new GetDeviceResolution((Demo) context);
            type_1_bodyTxt.setPadding(0, 0, 0, -(int) (getDeviceResolution.setHeight(0.06)));
        }else{
            GetDeviceResolution getDeviceResolution = new GetDeviceResolution((Demo) context);
            type_1_bodyTxt.setPadding(0, 0, 0, -(int) (getDeviceResolution.setHeight(0.02)));
        }
    }
    type_1_bodyTxt.setText(strBuilder);
    type_1_bodyTxt.setLinkTextColor(Color.RED);


    removeLine(type_1_bodyTxt, main_hrml);
    type_1_bodyTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

private void removeLine(TextView type_1_bodyTxt, String content){
    Spannable s = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(content);
    for (URLSpan u: s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class)) {
        s.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan() {
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
                tp.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        }, s.getSpanStart(u), s.getSpanEnd(u), 0);
    }

    type_1_bodyTxt.setText(s);
}



private void makeLinkClickable(SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span) {
    int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
    int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
    ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Do something with span.getURL() to handle the link click...
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", span.getURL());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
    strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}
```

**My WebActivity where I am passing url with Intent is **

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.astrolabe_web_link);

    loadUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    ImageView webClose = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.webClose);
    loadUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    if (loadUrl == null) {
    }

    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl(loadUrl);
}
```

}

Comment: Show the WebView Activity also.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on textview having link you must be opening activity having webview and loading the URL which you have on textview.

```js
webView.loadURL(textViewValue);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

WebViewClient will open the URL in your applications webview itself, no external browser will be opened

Comment: NOt like thas bro.. Actually here is underline inside textView.. Now When I click on it it opens my webView and everything is perfect but When I am removing my underline then this calling browser.. click event is not firing..

Comment: add onClickListener() on you textview then, if you don't want underline

Comment: @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
webView.loadUrl(url);
return true;
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132463/discussion-between-mrinmoy-and-target).